# 0x API swap destination address

Tags: 0x

Looks like there is no way to specify destination address for the swap function, is it so?
Is there a way such that the swapped to tokens will be sent to another address, but not the original sender's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible right now.